# how do i restrict not to select parent node in WinForm TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

In `winform` I want to `restrict only select child nodes` `not to select only parent node.`

I tried like following checked parent click and show message box.

```
TreeNode node = treeView.SelectedNode;
while (node.Parent != null)
{
    node = node.Parent;
} 

A
+-B
+-C
```

> Is there any other way to do so?

I want user able to select `B , C` but When He select `A` i want to show popup like `please select child node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why 'winforms-to-web' and 'node.js' tags?

On a c# Winform, maybe something like this, handling Treeview's AfterSelect event:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Parent == null && e.Node.Nodes.Count>0){
            MessageBox.Show("only child nodes must be selected", "warning");
            treeView1.SelectedNode=e.Node.Nodes[0];
        }
    }
```

And to avoid an initial message you can do this

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //tree load
        treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0];
        treeView1.ExpandAll();
    }
```

Or assign the handler after the tree load through code.